# Cloud Dataflow BQ output hung job for TLS handshake error from

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

My Cloud Dataflow job hangs.

Pipeline:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadFiles").from(options.getInputFile()).withCompressionType(CompressionType.GZIP))
.apply(new ProcessRecords(eventType))
.apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to(options.getOutput()).withSchema(options.getBigQuerySchema())
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
p.run();
```

From worker logs all I can see is

```
Kubelet is healthy?: true
TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:41759: EOF
shutdown[7231]: shutting down for system halt
```

The same job when I output to a GCS file it works fine.

JobID: `2016-12-28_15_23_54-4009520083656203603`

I have tried this multiple times but every time its the same issue.

Comment: Why do you think that the job hangs? I looked at the logs and it seems like it was a few minutes into importing data to BigQuery when it was cancelled by the user. Did you try waiting longer for it to complete?

Comment: The "shutdown" thing is normal operation. Dataflow shut down your workers while the BigQuery import job was running, in order to not waste resources.

Comment: @jktf I did w8 for like 5-10mins and then cancelled it. Do I need to w8 longer ? Will run it again

Comment: Yes, please wait longer. I didn't see any bad signs in this job - it should succeed.

Comment: I should have never seen the logs. All well. Job works fine. Given my previous experience, Dataflow was really fast, maybe that idea and the logs + some searches to old posts made me think something is wrong. Thanks @jktf

Comment: @Atrix1987 - you could post your own answer to help others in future that may experience the same ;-)

Comment: sure will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the pipeline construct code or data flow. **TextIO write operations are faster than BigQueryIO write**.

In case you every notice all your steps to simply move to **"Running"** state and not show the rate of processing or anything else, there is nothing wrong with it.

Digging into the worker logs might show TLS handshake error or shutdown or system halt. Thats absolutely normal. Just let the job run further and it should be fine.